How does vscode devcontainer persist extensions upon deletion of container?
While using vscode devcontainers extensions to attach my vscode to docker container,
I came to question that "how does vscode persists my extensions after container is deleted?"
for instance,

attach to running docker container
install c/c++ extensions
stop docker container
docker rm that container
re-start docker container
attach to running docker container via vscode
Ta-Da! find that C/C++ extension is installed.

I didn't configure my .devcontainer.json for default installation.
What I am suspecting is it maybe related to following option,

But I cannot find any volume mount related to vscode extensions (I ran docker inspect)
Is there any reasonable explanation about this?

Since container filesystems are intrinsically temporary, I'd generally assume the IDE is storing settings on your host system somewhere.  When you docker rm the container something needs to recreate it, and that could recreate the necessary environment inside the container too.
